# How to re-write subdirectory to subdomain

Tags: asp.net

I tried but fail to do:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="blog url rewrite">
      <match url="(.*)$" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mydomin.com/blog" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^mydomin/blog" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="cdn.mydomin.com/{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Can anyone please help me? I have asp.net webform application 4.5
And I want to re-write: mydomain.com/blog to blog.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<rules>
  <rule name="blog url rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="blog" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/blog.{C:1}" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(.*)/blog.*" />
    </conditions>
</rule>
```